# How to convert _bsontype objectID value to string/objectID to insert in mongoDB using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, objectid

I have a JSON file that contains object like bellow.

```
{
    userID: {"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"0":92,"1":237,"2":216,"3":42,"4":254,"5":178,"6":68,"7":182,"8":208,"9":254,"10":51,"11":64}},
    userName: "abc"
}
```

*Note*: Also have some nested fields like userID.

when trying to import to MongoDB using bulk insert getting error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: object [{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"0":92,"1":237,"2":216,"3":42,"4":254,"5":178,"6":68,"7":182,"8":208,"9":254,"10":51,"11":64}}] is not a valid ObjectId
```

How can I convert userID to objectID/string? like `ObjectId("5d1de1bab90f8bf15f58df3f")` or `"5d1de1bab90f8bf15f58df3f"`

The expected output in DB:

```
{
    userID: ObjectId("5d1de1bab90f8bf15f58df3f"),
    userName: "abc"
}
```

or

```
{
    userID: "5d1de1bab90f8bf15f58df3f",
    userName: "abc"
}
```

Comment: Where does that string for the object ID come from?

Comment: string for the object ID expected in DB and read from the JSON file @JackBashford

Comment: Can you control the output of JSON file? Or do you want to keep the JSON output like that and fix it at the input stage?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you rodamn,

You have put me on the right track. Just for the sake of it. This is my utility function. Verbose but it works.

```js
const { ObjectID } = require( 'mongodb' )

  toObjectID: function ( object ) {
    let hexString = ''
    Object.values(object.id).forEach(elem =>{
      const result = elem.toString(16)
      if(result.length === 2) {
        hexString += result
      } else {
        hexString += "0" + result
      }
    })
    const id = new ObjectID(hexString)
    return id
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation with ObjectID insertion that I was able to resolve. These steps -- though seeminly round-about for the situation -- would accomplish the goal:

**1**. Convert the id from array of base10 ints to string of base16 characters:

```
const idString = obj.userID.id.map(num => {
  var result = num.toString(16);
  return result.length == 2 ? num : "0" + num;
})
.join('');
```

**2**. Create an Object ID from string:

```
const _id = ObjectID(idString);
```

**3**. Convert back to string
Convert from an ObjectID back to the ObjectID() form that mongodb expects when inserting or updating documents:

```
_id.toString();
```